# didSelectRowAt not called for UITableView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView inside of a UIScrollView. The UITableView has scrolling disabled and has all the required delgates within the ViewController (as can be seen in the code below). However, when I click an item in the table, didSelectRowAt is never called (didHighlightRowAt is also never called). Why is it not called? How do I fix it?

```
class NewsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

private static let headlineArticleReuseIdentifier = "HeadlineArticleCell"
private static let categoryCellReuseIdentifier = "NewsCategoryCell"

@IBOutlet weak var headlineArticlesPreviewList: UITableView!
private var bindings = Set<AnyCancellable>()
private var viewModel: NewsViewModel = NewsViewModel()
private var headlineArticles: [Article] = []

@IBOutlet weak var headlineTitle: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    headlineArticlesPreviewList.delegate = self
    headlineArticlesPreviewList.dataSource = self
    
    let cancellable = viewModel.$viewState.sink(receiveValue: { state in
        switch state {
        case let .data(data):
            self.setData(data: data)
            print()
        case let .error(error):
            print(error)
        case .loading:
            print()
        }
    })
    bindings.insert(cancellable)
}

private func setData(data: NewsViewModel.ViewState.Data) {
    self.headlineArticles = data.headlineArticles
    self.headlineTitle.text = data.headlineCategory.displayName
    self.headlineArticlesPreviewList.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return headlineArticles.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = headlineArticlesPreviewList.dequeueReusableCell(
        withIdentifier: NewsViewController.headlineArticleReuseIdentifier,
        for: indexPath)
        as? HeadlineArticleTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("could not cast to headline article")
    }
    let headlineArticle = headlineArticles[indexPath.item]
    cell.setArticle(article: headlineArticle)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HeadlineArticleSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "HeadlineArticleSegue" {

       let detailViewController = segue.destination
            as! ArticleViewController

       let articleIndexPath = headlineArticlesPreviewList.indexPathForSelectedRow!
       let row = articleIndexPath.row
    detailViewController.article = headlineArticles[row]
    }
}
}
```

UITableView Settings

[image]

UITableView Inside UIScrollView
[image]

UITableViewCell Settings

[image]

Comment: Could you please refer, which settings of table view you customize?

Comment: Check UIScrollView contentsize. I supose in fact table view is diplayed right but something (like wrong contentsize of parent) prevent it to get touched ... You also have checked "can cancel on scroll" which is not good for your scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a storyboard segue set that had an incorrect restoration ID

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective this layout of elements in storyboard is not good.

I would suggest you to use 2 embedded views, 1 for tableview and other for collection view and use delegates on handling the didselect row for tableview and collectionview in those embedded view controllers and then use protocols and delegates to inform main view controller to do specific tasks.

With this approach your current view controller will be light and will do only specific tasks and will delegate rendering of table view and collection view to respective embedded view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

- storyboard segue set that has an incorrect restoration ID